# Write formula with double quote symbol in Excel with C#

Tags: c#, string, excel, office-automation

I would like to write a formula in a Excel cell.
I managed to write simple formula but I have an issue with the following formula :

`=IF(OR(ISBLANK(I20631);ISBLANK(F20631));"";I20631=F20631)`

In my C# programm it tried this :

```
ExcelWorksheet.Cells[row, column] = "=IF(OR(ISBLANK(I" + row +");ISBLANK(F" + row +"));\"\";I"+ row +"=F" + row +")";
```

I have an exeption because of the \"\" (I think so)

When I write in the excel cell, Excel cannot interpeter \" as the double quote symbole " 
And I can't write a string with visual studio whithout writting the \"

Is it possible to have another way to write a string with double quote character whitout using \" ?
(I alos tried `"` but it is still interpreted as \" )

Thank you in advance,

Thomas

Comment: What exception are you getting? I think it's more likely that the `+ row` gives you an exception rather than the `\"`. Try replacing `+ row` with `+ row.ToString()`.

Comment: I changed row to row.tostring() and (char)34 but I still have the following exception : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Source="" ErrorCode=-2146827284 StackTrace: at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData) –

Answer (score 1):

Yes, put an @ before the string. This will "disabled" the escape character `\`. The only thing that is enabled is the use of two double quotes which will translate into one double quote.

Example:

```
 "I said: \"Hello!\""
```

is equal to:

```
 @"I said: ""Hello!"""
```

is equal to:

```
 "I said: " + (char)34 + "Hello!" + (char)34
```

Which will producte when printed:

```
 I said: "Hello!"
```

**Be aware**: How ever you format your string, the debugger will ALWAYS show your string as the first string, with `\`. This does not mean that these backslashes are part of the string, it is just a way of showing them.

Answer (score 0):

As Roy mentioned, the compiler should take the String without backslash if you escape like you did, but you can also give the Verbatim String Literal Martin mentioned a try..

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx) for examples of them..